# bashでrustのソースからstructの一覧を作りたい

Tags: bash

rustのソースからstructの一覧を作成したいです。
bashで以下のようなコードを組んであと一歩というところまで来ました。

```
for src in $(find . | grep .rs$)
do
   grep struct $src
done
```

このコードを実行すると例えば以下のような結果が得られます

```
pub struct VarData {
pub struct Assignment {
pub struct Stats {
struct Watcher {
pub struct Lit(u32);
pub struct Var(u32);
```

ここからあと一歩進めて、

```
VarData
Assignment
Stats
Watcher
Lit(u32)
Var(u32)
```

という感じの出力を得たいのですが、どのようにbashを組めばいいでしょうか？
structの次の単語を得る？という感じかと思ってますが。。。
あるいはbashでなくてもcargoなどで同様の機能があったりしますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

申し訳ありません。あとだしじゃんけんで大変、心苦しいのですが今回、対象としたいデータは全部で以下になります。
今度こそ全部です。

```
pub struct MainOptions {
struct Subst<'s, S: 's> {
struct DimacsParser<'p> {
pub struct RegionAllocator {
pub struct DecisionLevel(LevelIndex);
pub struct VarData {
pub struct Assignment {
pub struct DirIter<'a> {
pub struct RevIter<'a> {
pub struct Clause {
pub struct ClauseRef(allocator::Ref);
pub struct ClauseAllocator {
pub struct ClauseGC<'a> {
struct LegacyCounter {
pub struct IdxMap<K: Idx, V> {
pub struct Iter<'a, K: Idx, V: 'a> {
pub struct IterMut<'a, K: Idx, V: 'a> {
pub struct IdxVec<K: Idx, V> {
pub struct IdxHeap<K: Idx> {
pub struct Lit(u32);
pub struct Var(u32);
pub struct Budget {
pub struct BacktrackableFormula {
pub struct BacktrackConflict<'a> {
pub struct BacktrackDecide<'a> {
pub struct ClauseDBSettings {
pub struct Stats {
pub struct ClauseDB {
pub struct AnalyzeContext {
pub struct DecisionHeuristicSettings {
struct VarLine {
pub struct DecisionHeuristic {
pub struct Random {
pub struct ElimClauses {
pub struct VarStatus {
pub struct ElimQueue {
struct OccLine {
pub struct OccLists {
pub struct ElimOcc {
pub struct SubsumptionQueue {
pub struct SimplificatorSettings {
struct Stats {
pub struct Touched {
pub struct Simplificator {
struct Watcher {
struct WatchesLine {
pub struct Watches {
pub struct RestartStrategy {
pub struct LearningStrategy {
struct LearningGuard {
struct SimplifyGuard {
struct Stats {
pub struct SearchSettings {
pub struct SearcherSettings {
pub struct SearchCtx {
pub struct Searcher {
pub struct CoreSettings {
pub struct CoreSolver {
pub struct SimpSettings {
pub struct SimpSolver {
pub struct Stats {
```

pub struct IterMut<'a, K: Idx, V: 'a> {
などにも対応するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

Comment: はい、それでお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU find と GNU grep を利用する場合。

```bash
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.9.0
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.8

$ find . -type f -regex '.*\.rs$' -exec grep -Po '(?<=struct )(.+?)(?=( *{|;))' {} +                                                                                      
VarData
Assignment
Stats
Watcher
Lit(u32)
Var(u32)
```